# PDO passing bool values rather than the bind values

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-update, mysql-insert-id

I'm trying to add an entry into a table if it doesnt exist of update it if it does exist.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO company 
                (userid, companyName, registeredAddress, registeredPostcode) 
        VALUES ($userid, companyName = :companyName, registeredAddress = :registeredAddress, registeredPostcode = :registeredPostcode) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            companyName = :companyName,
            registeredAddress = :registeredAddress, 
            registeredPostcode = :registeredPostcode;";  

$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['companyName' => $companyname, 
                'registeredAddress' => $registeredaddress,          
                'registeredPostcode' => $registeredpostcode]);
```

If the userid already exists then the update works perfectly.

If there is no userid it creates a row with teh user id but then places 0 or 1 in the other fields. 0 if there is a value and 1 if no value is passed.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please, if you are going to use a prepared parameterised query use Parameters for ALL the values not just some!!

Comment: THEN Check the syntax for a `VALUES()` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks wrong. In the `insert`'s `values` clause you just need to pass the values, not `=` expressions:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO company (userid, companyName, registeredAddress, registeredPostcode) VALUES ($userid, :companyName, :registeredAddress, :registeredPostcode) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE companyName = :companyName,registeredAddress = :registeredAddress, registeredPostcode = :registeredPostcode;";
```

Side note:
`$userid` should probably be passed as a bind variable too (it wasn't in the original code)

Comment: Thank you so much Mureinik. This has been driving me crazy! This is all new to me and I'm trying to teach myself. - with The $userid I was entering this directly as it was not coming form the user entered data. I'll pass it as a bind variable too though.